# PHP - Cannot send image via mysqli_stmt_send_long_data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a logging system for which I wish the user to save their profile image along with basic info (name, username, password). For this, I have coded these files:

The HTML form (at index.php):

```
<form id='signupform' enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <table style='margin: 0px auto; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0 1em; color: #ffffff;'>
            <tr>
              <th colspan='2'>
                <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
                <p>
                  Please fill out ALL the fields
                </p>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='2'>
                <div id='signuperror' style='display: block; width: 100%; height: 20px; border: 2px solid #ff0000; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #ff0000; text-align: center; opacity: 0;'>Username is taken!</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style='text-align: right;'>
                First Name:
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='fname' type='text' name='first' placeholder='First Name' onkeyup="checkComplete('signup');" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style='text-align: right;'>
                Last Name:
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='lname' type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last Name' onkeyup="checkComplete('signup');" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='2' style='text-align: center;'>
                <input id='usrimg' type='file' accept='image/*' name='userimage' style='display: none;' />
                <table style='width: 100%;'>
                  <tr>
                    <td style='width: 90%;'>
                      <button type='button' class='popbtn' onclick='browseImage();' style='width: 100%;'>Profile Image</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 10%;'>
                      <img id='imgstats' style='vertical-align: middle; display: none;' src='imgsuccess.png' />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style='text-align: right;'>
                Username:
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='username' type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username' onfocusout="checkUID(this.value);" onkeyup="checkComplete('signup');" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style='text-align: right;'>
                Password:
              </td>
              <td>
                <input id='password' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password' onkeyup="checkComplete('signup');" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='2'  style='text-align: center;'>
                <button type='button' id='signupbtn' class='popbtn' disabled='disabled'>SIGN UP</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

So, the css may confuse a bit, but basically the form is as follows:

```
<form id='signupform' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id='fname' type='text' name='first' />
  <input id='lname' type='text' name='last' />
  <input id='usrimg' type='file' name='userimage' />
  <input id='username' type='text' name='uid' />
  <input id='password' type='password' name='pwd' />
  <button type='button' id='signupbtn'>SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

So the `signupbtn` button has an `onclick` event attached upon document load (also at index.php; I'm not showing it all as it is not relevant for this):

```
$(function() {
      $('#signupbtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "signup.php",
          data: $('#signupform').serialize(),
          success: function(response){
            //...
          }
        });
        return false;
      });

  //...

});
```

So I use ajax to call the file `signup.php` to submit the form without refreshing. Then on that file:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include('connect.php');

  $first = $_POST['first'];
  $last = $_POST['last'];
  $img = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['userimage']['tmp_name']));
  $uid = $_POST['uid'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

  $query = "insert into Users (first, last, img, uid, pwd) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssbss', $first, $last, $img, $uid, $pwd);
  mysqli_stmt_send_long_data($stmt, 2, $img);
  $res = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  echo $res;
?>
```

I retrieve all the info from the form, then use `mysqli_stmt_send_long_data` to attempt at inserting my image into the Table, which is created on connect.php:

```
<?php
  $host_name  = "xxx";
  $database   = "xxx";
  $user_name  = "xxx";
  $password   = "xxx";


  $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo '<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';
  }
  else {
    //echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

    if ($db_selected) {
      $userTableName = 'Users';

      $userTableExists = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from $userTableName");
      if (!$userTableExists) {
        echo 'The table ' . $userTableName . ' does not exist. Creating...<br /><br />';

        $sqlCreateTable = "create table " . $userTableName . "( id int(11) not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                                                first varchar(128) not null,
                                                                last varchar(128) not null,
                                                                img longblob not null,
                                                                uid varchar(128) not null,
                                                                pwd varchar(1000) not null)";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlCreateTable);

        if ($result) {
                    echo 'Table ' . $userTableName . ' created...<br>';
                }
                else {
                    die("Cannot create table " . $userTableName . ": " . mysql_error());
                }
      }
    }
    else {
            die("Cannot use " . $database . ": " . mysql_error());
        }
  }
?>
```

As you'd expect since I'm asking the question, the Ajax ends in success and the row is inserted. But as I check phpMyAdmin on my site's database, I get that the `img` field has a value of `[BLOB - 0 B]` which can only mean that the image uploading is not working. What could be the case? I have found very little on send_long_data not working, but maybe someone has had this same issue. Thank you for any answers in advance.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: What is the field type of the column?

Comment: @Alex Howansky yeah, I'm getting to that. This is not going to be my final version. If I can, I want to learn to salt the password and such, but I started doing the image inserting and got stuck here!

Comment: @Jay Blanchard the field type is `longblob`

Comment: That was @AlexHowansky's comment but I'll back him up. You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I think you shouldn't escape binary image data by `mysqli_real_escape_string` as it will destroy it, you already binding data to query, you don't need to escape it. I would also recommend checking for errors, and check if file was even uploaded correctly. After all, even if you manage to store  image in database, you will need then insert it in your code as base64 encoded dataurl or create yourself a script that will send binary image data with correct headers.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't store the image in the database. I would store it on the server and then put the path to the image in the database. BLOB's are notoriously slow.

Comment: So the image would only be a varchar URL?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I guess it makes sense since I'm only given 1GB of database space to work with. I'll work on updating this and will edit my question to include changes. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

After suggestion from [Jay Blanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard) I decided to discard the BLOB idea and instead save string information about the images. For this, I first modified the `connect.php` file to create a better version of the table:

```
<?php
  $host_name  = "xxx";
  $database   = "xxx";
  $user_name  = "xxx";
  $password   = "xxx";


  $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo '<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';
  }
  else {
    //echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connect, $database);

    if ($db_selected) {
      $userTableName = 'Users';

      $userTableExists = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from $userTableName");
      if (!$userTableExists) {
        echo 'The table ' . $userTableName . ' does not exist. Creating...<br /><br />';

        $sqlCreateTable = "create table " . $userTableName . "( id int(11) not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                                                first varchar(128) not null,
                                                                last varchar(128) not null,
                                                                sex varchar(1) not null,
                                                                img varchar(5) not null,
                                                                uid varchar(128) not null,
                                                                pwd varchar(1000) not null)";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlCreateTable);

        if ($result) {
                    echo 'Table ' . $userTableName . ' created...<br>';
                }
                else {
                    die("Cannot create table " . $userTableName . ": " . mysql_error());
                }
      }
    }
    else {
            die("Cannot use " . $database . ": " . mysql_error());
        }
  }
?>
```

So now there are two new fields: sex (1 character to save either 'm' or 'f'), and img (up to 5 characters to save image EXTENSION). What makes this important is that, to attempt at making this form feel more complete, an user should be given the chance to choose an image of their own, or opt for a temporary default image. This is why the sex field is important and what reflects the changes in the form:

```
<form id='signupform' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id='fname' type='text' name='first' />
  <input id='lname' type='text' name='last' />
  I am <input type='radio' name='sex' value='m' />Male <input type='radio' name='sex' value='f' />Female
  <input id='usrimg' type='file' name='userimage' />
  <input type='checkbox' id='imgdef' />Use a default image for now
  <input id='username' type='text' name='uid' />
  <input id='password' type='password' name='pwd' />
  <button type='button' id='signupbtn'>SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

So now, when I press the `signupbtn`, two ajax functions are called in, depending whether or not the checkbox is checked:

```
$(function() {
      $('#signupbtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var filextension;

        if (!(document.getElementById('imgdef').checked)) {
          filextension = $('#usrimg').val().substr($('#usrimg').val().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

          var fdata = new FormData();
          fdata.append('first', $('#fname').val());
          fdata.append('last', $('#lname').val());
          fdata.append('sex', $("#signupform input[type='radio']:checked").val());
          fdata.append('userimage', $('#usrimg').prop("files")[0]);
          fdata.append('uid', $('#username').val());
          fdata.append('pwd', $('#password').val());
          fdata.append('filextension', filextension);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "uploadimage.php",
            data: fdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
          });
        }
        else filextension = 'no';

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "signup.php",
          data: $('#signupform').serialize() + '&filextension=' + filextension,
          success: function(response) {
            //...
          }
        });
      });

      //...
});
```

If the checkbox is not checked, then the user has to upload their own image. In this case, I make a FormData for proper upload under ajax (**Note: I lost a good deal of time assigning the `signupform` as parameter. The file will never upload this way**), then when everything has been appended, I call the ajax function that will call `uploadimage.php`:

```
<?php
  include('connect.php');

  $res = mysqli_query($connect, "select count(1) from Users");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
  $imgnum = $row[0];

  $dir = 'Users/';
  $ext = $_POST['filextension'];
  $file = $dir . 'user' . $imgnum . '.' . $ext;

  $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userimage']['tmp_name'], $file);
?>
```

The code is simpler than it seems. While it is always recommended to check if the file is an image, if the size is correct, and such, I am already doing this in javascript so I didn't even bother here. Here, I get the number of rows of the `Users` table, so that I can get which user will be next. I do this because I found more convenient to save the uploaded images with generic names (in this case, depending on if there are n rows in the table, the new user's image would be saved as `usern.ext`, where ext would be the extension(jpg, png, gif, etc)) rather than having to keep the whole string of the original image's name.

In the case the user is opting for a default, the extension becomes a `no` to indicate upon its display. Basically, there is another form in `index.php` which is used to log in, providing username and password, to a file named `signin.php`:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  include('connect.php');

  $uid = $_POST['signinuid'];
  $pwd = $_POST['signinpwd'];

  $sql = "select * from Users where uid='$uid' and pwd='$pwd'";
  $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

  $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
  $_SESSION['first'] = $row['first'];
  $_SESSION['last'] = $row['last'];
  $_SESSION['sex'] = $row['sex'];
  $_SESSION['img'] = $row['img'];
  $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];

  header("Location: http://....php");
?>
```

So when the user logs in, all these values are stored in $_SESSION, then the page refreshes. This is so that, if a user is logged in, their info can be shown, instead of prompting to sign up or sign in (which gets hidden), along with a sign out button:

```
<?php
      if ($_SESSION['id']) {
        $soutid = 'signout';
        echo "<table style='margin: 0px auto;'>";
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'>";
              echo "<h1>WELCOME!</h1>";
            echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
              if ($_SESSION['img'] == 'no') {
                echo "<img src='Users/" . $_SESSION['sex'] . "def.png' alt=''>";
              }
              else echo "<img src='Users/user" . $_SESSION['id'] . "." . $_SESSION['img'] . "' alt=''>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
              echo "<div style='color: #007146; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;'>";
                echo $_SESSION['first'] . " " . $_SESSION['last'] . "(" . $_SESSION['uid'] . ")";
              echo "</div>";
            echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'>";
              echo "<form id='$soutid' method='POST' action='signout.php'>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='popbtn'>Sign Out</a>";
              echo "</form>";
            echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
      }
    ?>
```

This is where all my scheming comes together, as if `$_SESSION['img']` is `no`, then I call the default images, `mdef.png` and `fdef.png`, depending on what the user chose upon signing up, with this line:

```
echo "<img src='Users/" . $_SESSION['sex'] . "def.png' alt=''>";
```

And, if the user provided an image, I call it with their id and the extension that was stored:

```
echo "<img src='Users/user" . $_SESSION['id'] . "." . $_SESSION['img'] . "' alt=''>";
```

I'm not showing all of my code because I want to complete my form first. I have not worked on hashing the password, confirmation email, password recovery, and user profile pages (both to see a non-logged in user, and to see the user's to edit as they please). Once I finish with this, I'll record my progress and leave a link to a video here. Thanks to all who helped me out to this state.

**LAST EDIT:** The project is now finished! You will find a demonstration video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLpbKdTY_xo&t=2s